How do you merge cells in a pivot table?
I have an excel sheet where there is a header referring to 3 columns each.
Lets assume for instance this is "Pets owned"
Each row is the data for a person and we can look down the cells to see what they have- everyone will have something in the first 1 even if its "None".
Some people will have something in all 3.
Making a pivot table for this on the surface seems easy. I just fix the header so its copied 3 times rather than 1 and then I pick the row of the first one and the values of all 3.
However I notice this doesn't work- if somebody has something not mentioned in the first row by anyone else for their third option this simply will not be counted.
Is there anyway I can setup a pivot table so it gives me the complete values for each of the 3 columns?
I am uninterested in combinations. I purely want overall numbers. How many people say dog, how many say cat, does anyone happen to say mongoose (which if they're the only one and its their 3rd option will be missed)
It strikes me there should be a simple way to get this but I'm stuck manually counting at the moment.

COUNTIF maybe?

It would be great to provide some sample data, otherwise its difficult to follow. In any case, it doesn't sound like even a Pivot Table would be necessary.

It looks like you want something like this:

So in H2 use =FILTER(UNIQUE(TOCOL($B$2:$D$5)),UNIQUE(TOCOL($B$2:$D$5))<>"")
And in I2 use =COUNTIF($B$2:$D$5,H2#)
Change to the desired ranges.
